# Can't get out parameter of Oracle in .net

Tags: .net, plsql

As i said in title, problem is -  out parameter of oracle of procedure is null in .net ,although this parameter is assigned in pl/sql testing. Out parameter datatype is nvarchar2. I tried to change this value to int, and it worked well. But i need to return text from procedure!!! What is the issue? BTW i use using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
Here is the code:

```
private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float cur_rate;
    decimal value;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(RateTxtBox.Text) && decimal.TryParse(RateTxtBox.Text, out value))
    {
    cur_rate = float.Parse(RateTxtBox.Text);
    con = new OracleConnection(conStr);
    con.Open();
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.BindByName = true;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = schema_name + ".CACCRUEMENT_INS";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_check_info_id", OracleDbType.Int32, header_id, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_calculate_on", OracleDbType.Date, DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text), ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_curr_id", OracleDbType.Decimal, CurrencyCombobox.SelectedValue, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_cur_rate", OracleDbType.Decimal, Decimal.Parse(RateTxtBox.Text), ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_result", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    //cmd.Parameters.Add("p_result", OracleDbType.NVarchar2,ParameterDirection.Output);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    string result = cmd.Parameters["p_result"].Value.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(result);
    Thread.Sleep(2);
    this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid data format!");
    }
}
```

---

Pl/sql precedure:

```
create or replace procedure CACCRUEMENT_INS(
p_check_info_id in number,
p_calculate_on in date,
p_curr_id in number,
p_cur_rate in number,
p_result out varchar2
) is

v_Accruemtnt number;
v_rate number;
v_cur_rate_in_check_info number;
Last_accruemet_date date;
monthes_bwn_last_adj_n_chck number;
next_check date;
check_info_rate number;
begin
select c.next_check 
into next_check 
from check_info c 
where c.id_check_info = p_check_info_id;
begin 
  select max(c.calculate_on) 
  into Last_accruemet_date 
  from Caccruement c 
  where c.fk_check_info = p_check_info_id
  group by c.fk_check_info;
  exception when no_data_found then
  begin 
    select max(c.calculate_on_date) 
    into Last_accruemet_date 
    from check_info_lines  c 
    where c.fk_check_info = p_check_info_id 
    group by c.fk_check_info;
  exception when no_data_found then
    p_result:='Adjustment is not calculated!';
    goto l_EndOfLoop;
  end;   
end;
select ci.curency_rate 
into check_info_rate from check_info ci where ci.id_check_info = p_check_info_id;
select c.rate 
into v_rate 
from Check_Info c 
where c.id_check_info = p_check_info_id;
monthes_bwn_last_adj_n_chck:=MONTHS_BETWEEN(next_check,Last_accruemet_date);
IF(monthes_bwn_last_adj_n_chck>round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(p_calculate_on,Last_accruemet_date),3))
THEN
  select c.curency_rate 
  into v_cur_rate_in_check_info 
  from check_info c 
  where c.id_check_info = p_check_info_id;
  --v_rate:=round((v_rate/v_cur_rate_in_check_info),3);  
v_Accruemtnt := round(v_rate/check_info_rate * MONTHS_BETWEEN(p_calculate_on, Last_accruemet_date)*p_cur_rate,3) ;
insert 
into CAccruement(Id_Accruemtnt,Calculate_On,Accruemtnt,Fk_Check_Info,Cu_Id,Cu_Rate,Calculation_Date,Accruemtnt_Kzt) 
values (accruement_seq.nextval,p_calculate_on,round(v_Accruemtnt/p_cur_rate,3),p_check_info_id,p_curr_id,p_cur_rate,Sysdate,v_Accruemtnt);
update check_info c 
set c.total_accumulated = c.total_accumulated+v_Accruemtnt 
where c.id_check_info = p_check_info_id;
END IF; 
 COMMIT; 
 p_result:='Operation complited successfully';
 update_total_accumulated(p_check_info_id);
<<l_EndOfLoop>>
  ROLLBACK;
  EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS
THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
  ROLLBACK;    
end CACCRUEMENT_INS;
```

Answer (score 0):

- First of all try using  the db type `Varchar2` instead of `NVarchar2`

  Ex.

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_result", OracleDbType.NVarchar2,ParameterDirection.Output);
```

- Second if you still are not getting the value try in the following to get it back

```
    var value = cmd.Parameters["p_result"].Value;
    var str = (OracleString) value;
    str.Value; //This is the string
```

Comment: Throws OracleNullValue Excaption on last line.

Comment: Ok Maybe it is null. Could you try assigning a value to the p_result variable at the beginning of the procedure? 
Aside of that you will never get a no_data_found exception when using a group function like **max**.