# Can't get out parameter of oracle in.net

Tags: .net, plsql

I has been 2 day since i'm trying to get out parameter out of pl/sql procedure in .net.
I user ODAC(ORACLE DATA ACESS CLIENT). Here is my prevuouse question.[Can't get out parameter of Oracle in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607923/cant-get-out-parameter-of-oracle-in-net/12628179#12628179)

Now, i changed procedure to function and try to return varchar 2 value.

C# CODE

```
float cur_rate;
            decimal value;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(RateTxtBox.Text) && decimal.TryParse(RateTxtBox.Text, out value))
            {
            cur_rate = float.Parse(RateTxtBox.Text);
            con = new OracleConnection(conStr);
            con.Open();
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.BindByName = true;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = schema_name + ".CACCRUEMENT_INS_FUNC";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_check_info_id", OracleDbType.Int32, header_id, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_calculate_on", OracleDbType.Date, DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text), ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_curr_id", OracleDbType.Decimal, CurrencyCombobox.SelectedValue, ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_cur_rate", OracleDbType.Decimal, Decimal.Parse(RateTxtBox.Text), ParameterDirection.Input);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_result", OracleDbType.Decimal,ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("RETURN_VAL", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int result = Int16.Parse(cmd.Parameters["RETURN_VAL"].Value.ToString());
```

It throws an `{"ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small\nORA-06512: at line 1"}`

pl/sql function

```
create or replace function CACCRUEMENT_INS_FUNC(
      p_check_info_id in number,
      p_calculate_on in date,
      p_curr_id in number,
      p_cur_rate in number,
      p_result out number)return varchar2 is

  v_Accruemtnt number;
  v_rate number;
  v_cur_rate_in_check_info number;
  Last_accruemet_date date;
  monthes_bwn_last_adj_n_chck number;
  next_check date;
  check_info_rate number;
begin
  select c.next_check 
  into next_check 
  from check_info c 
  where c.id_check_info = p_check_info_id;
  begin 
        select max(c.calculate_on_date) 
        into Last_accruemet_date 
        from check_info_lines  c 
        where c.fk_check_info = p_check_info_id 
        group by c.fk_check_info;


        if Last_accruemet_date > p_calculate_on then 
          --p_result :=2;--'Accruement date must be between date of last adjustment and next C-Check date!';
          return 'Accruement date must be between date of last adjustment and next C-Check date!';
          goto l_EndOfLoop;
        end if;

        exception when no_data_found then
        --p_result:=0;--'Adjustment is not calculated!';
        return 'Adjustment is not calculated!';
        goto l_EndOfLoop;

        begin
          select max(c.calculate_on) 
          into Last_accruemet_date 
          from Caccruement c 
          where c.fk_check_info = p_check_info_id
          group by c.fk_check_info;

        exception when no_data_found then
          null;
        end;
      end;
    select ci.curency_rate 
    into check_info_rate 
    from check_info ci 
    where ci.id_check_info = p_check_info_id;

    select c.rate 
    into v_rate 
    from Check_Info c 
    where c.id_check_info = p_check_info_id;

    monthes_bwn_last_adj_n_chck:=MONTHS_BETWEEN(next_check,Last_accruemet_date);

    IF(monthes_bwn_last_adj_n_chck>round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(p_calculate_on,Last_accruemet_date),3))
    THEN
      select c.curency_rate 
      into v_cur_rate_in_check_info 
      from check_info c 
      where c.id_check_info = p_check_info_id;

    v_Accruemtnt := round(v_rate/check_info_rate * MONTHS_BETWEEN(p_calculate_on, Last_accruemet_date)*p_cur_rate,3) ;

    insert 
    into CAccruement(Id_Accruemtnt,Calculate_On,Accruemtnt,Fk_Check_Info,Cu_Id,Cu_Rate,Calculation_Date,Accruemtnt_Kzt) 
    values (accruement_seq.nextval,p_calculate_on,round(v_Accruemtnt/p_cur_rate,3),p_check_info_id,p_curr_id,p_cur_rate,Sysdate,v_Accruemtnt);

    update check_info c 
    set c.total_accumulated = c.total_accumulated+v_Accruemtnt 
    where c.id_check_info = p_check_info_id;
    END IF; 
     COMMIT; 

     --p_result:=1;--'Operation complited successfully';
     return 'Operation complited successfully';
     update_total_accumulated(p_check_info_id);

    <<l_EndOfLoop>>
      ROLLBACK;
      EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN

      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
      p_result:=3;--'Oracle not handled exception!';
      ROLLBACK;    
end CACCRUEMENT_INS_FUNC;
```

Comment: I have no experience with .net, but with the oracle side. I assume ,that during runtime your function will be called in some anonymous pl/sql block, assembled with the info provided about the parameters and return value. If that is the case, then the varchar2 variable used in that statement needs a length. Is there any way for you to define/configure/set a size for "OracleDbType.Varchar2"?

Comment: Yes, i have already solved it. I should have chooce other overloaded method of OracleComomand.Cmd.Parameters.Add() methed ,that hold the length of return value. Thanks!!